# Kendo Datetimepicker casting shadow on reset

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using Kendo DateTimePicker.

Here is my example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/IxALA/2

My example does:

1. Initialize the Datetimepicker
2. After 2 seconds simulate a reset (I reset it to another date)

Problem:
The Datetimepicker gets an ugly shadow around the top and bottom on reset. How can I avoid this?

Here is the Kendo documentation on reseting the Datetimepicker:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#methods-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer here](http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket.aspx?threadid=959892)

```
<div style="width:240px">
  <input id="datetimepicker" />
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
      value: new Date(2010,10,34)
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        var picker = $("#datetimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
        picker.value(new Date(2015, 10, 10));
    },2000);
  </script>
```